# @encoding for type id where id is actually any object

Tags: ios, objective-c, types, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I have a following method.

```
- (void)someObject:(id)obj {
  char* encoding = @encoding(typeof(obj));
  NSString *s = [NSString stringWithCString:encoding encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(s);
}
```

this method always return `@"@"` whether I pass a variable of type `NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary or NSString` in obj. I assume it is checking the `obj` pointer type.

What do I have to do so that it returns the actual type encoding of the variable that I have passed?

Comment: What do you mean by 'type encoding for the variable'? What are you expecting?

Comment: The point is that it would be a non sense to dereference an `id` opaque type (so @encode response is right since an `id` is an object which means `@`)...out of curiosity, what do you try to accomplish with that?

Comment: @HepaKKes: I am trying to assign the values to a class's ivars from a dictionary. I have  a list of Ivars ( using class_copyIvarList() ) and I have got the ivar type ( using ivar_getTypeEncoding() ), Now i want to make sure that the ivar is being filled with compatible values. ( e.g. an NSArray ivar should be filled with NSArray ). i can do if/else checks using isKindOfClass, but I was thinking whether there is another way where i just compare the type encoding of ivar and the incoming parameter.

Comment: @Merlevede : please see my comment above,

Answer (score 2):

`@encode()` is a compile-time construct; it only knows about the *variable's* type, not the class of the object that will be contained in the object at runtime. Any object-typed variable will encode to `@`.

You will have to use runtime checks, asking the objects for their classes, to accomplish your goal.